# Estimator of autocovariance in a wide-sense stationary process

Tags: time-series, stationarity

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process

> One can discuss the ergodicity of various properties of a stochastic
>   process. For example, a wide-sense stationary process $x(t)$ has mean
>   $m_x(t)= E[x(t)]$ and autocovariance $r_x(\tau) = E[(x(t)-m_x(t))
>  (x(t+\tau)-m_x(t+\tau))]$ which do not change with time. One way to
>   estimate the mean is to perform a time average: $$
>      \hat{m}_x(t)_{T} = \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} x(t) \, dt.$$
>
> If $\hat{m}_x(t)_{T}$ converges in squared mean to $m_x(t)$ as $T
> > \rightarrow \infty$, then the process x(t) is said to be
>   mean-ergodic[1] or mean-square ergodic in the first moment.[2]
>
> Likewise, one can estimate the autocovariance $r_x(\tau)$ by
>   performing a time average: $$
>      \hat{r}_x(\tau) = \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} [x(t+\tau)-m_x(t+\tau)] [x(t)-m_x(t)] \, dt.$$
>
> If this expression converges in squared mean to the true
>   autocovariance $r_x(\tau) = E[(x(t+\tau)-m_x(t+\tau)) (x(t)-m_x(t))]$,
>   then the process is said to be autocovariance-ergodic or mean-square
>   ergodic in the second moment.[2]
>
> A process which is ergodic in the first and second moments is
>   sometimes called ergodic in the wide sense.

I wonder if $m_x$ should be $\hat{m}_x$ instead in the definition of $\hat{r}_x(\tau)$, i.e. 
$$
    \hat{r}_x(\tau) = \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} [x(t+\tau)-m_x(t+\tau)] [x(t)-m_x(t)] \, dt$$

should be

$$
    \hat{r}_x(\tau) = \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} [x(t+\tau)-\hat{m}_x(t+\tau)] [x(t)-\hat{m}_x(t)] \, dt$$

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, whenever $m_x$ is unknown.